# Why does this variadic C function not print the first argument?

Tags: c, gcc, variadic-functions, variadic, variadic-macros

I am trying to make a variadic function in C with stdarg.h, and I followed this tutorial and wrote the code exactly as he did: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S-ak715zIIE. I included the output in the code. I cannot figure out why the first argument is not printed, and also, why are there zeros printed at the end? I am beyond confused. Thanks!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

void printNums(int num, ...) {
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, num);

    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        int value = va_arg(args, int);
        printf("%d: %d\n", i, value);
    }

    va_end(args);
}

int main() {
    printNums(5, 2, 3, 4);
    return 0;
}

/*
Output:
0: 2
1: 3
2: 4
3: 0
4: 0
*/
```

Comment: `printNums(5, 2, 3, 4);` This promises `5` more arguments to `printNum`, but only `3` follow, and the number of arguments itself (`num` in `printNums`) is never printed.

Comment: If you look at the code, you'll see that the first parameter is the amount of numbers that follow it. To use the `va_*` macros you need to have at least one non-`...` parameter, and must know how many parameters to expect (and their types), so there's no way around it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`va_start`'s first argument is the *last* parameter that *isn't* variadic.  So `num` holds the 5, and the rest hold the variadics:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

void printNums(int num, ...) {
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, num);

    printf("%d: %d\n", 0, num);
    for (int i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
        int value = va_arg(args, int);
        printf("%d: %d\n", i, value);
    }

    va_end(args);
}

int main() {
    printNums(5, 2, 3, 4);
    return 0;
}
```

```
0: 5
1: 2
2: 3
3: 4
4: 0
5: 0
```

> also, why are there zeros printed at the end? I am beyond confused. Thanks!

Because of this line:

```
    for (int i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
```

You pass the value `5` as `num` to `printNums()`.  In the for loop you act as though it describes the number of variadic arguments to read, but it doesn't - you passed 3 variadics, not 5.  The last 2 calls to `va_start` therefore yield undefined behavior, since you've read past the end of valid variadic arguments.  It's just mere chance that you happen to get 0 here - it could be some other random value.

Note that there is *no way* with mere variadic macros to know how *many* arguments were passed.  Nor is there a way to assert their *type*.  You can assume their type and specify their length at runtime if you wish:

```
$ ./t3
0: 5
1: 2
2: 3
3: 4
```

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

void printNums(int num, ...) {
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, num);

    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        int value = va_arg(args, int);
        printf("%d: %d\n", i, value);
    }

    va_end(args);
}

int main() {
    printNums(4, 5, 2, 3, 4);
    return 0;
}
```

Variadic functions are primarily valuable when writing functions like `printf`, where unknown types and quantities of arguments are required (see [the example from the man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/stdarg.3.html))  Using passing a list of known types would be more conveniently accomplished by passing an array and count int:

```
$ cat t.c
#include <stdio.h>

void printNums(int count, int* nums) {
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        printf("%d: %d\n", i, nums[i]);
    }
}

int main() {
    int nums[] = {5,2,3,4};
    printNums(4, nums);
    return 0;
}
```

that just doesn't make a very good video about variadics :P

Comment: using `int nums[] = {5,2,3,4};` the number of elements is known at compile time and you do not need to give *4* by yourself as a literal in `printNums(4, nums);` with the risk to have it wrong if the number of element is changed, be lazy and let the compiler count for you, also making your code more robust

Comment: in this case that's true, but `printNums()` doesn't know whether its true for any given array, so it needs to know the size.

Comment: sure, I just say to replace `4` by `sizeof(nums)/sizeof(*nums))` to have `printNums(sizeof(nums)/sizeof(*nums)), nums);` allowing to send the right number even you add/remove value in the initialization list

Comment: only if the array is full though.

Comment: it is full by definition because its number of elements is determined by its initialization